# Let $(window).blur and $('#id').click perform same function

Tags: jquery

I've got 2 different events that I want to have the same functions performed on. How do I 'merge' them?

```
$(window).blur(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    togglebackground();
});

$("#show-wall-link, #maximage, iframe").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    togglebackground();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).blur(togglebackground);
$("#show-wall-link, #maximage, iframe").click(togglebackground);

function togglebackground(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do stuff...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... they're functions. Anonymous inline-functions at the moment, but you could make any function an event listener.

```
function blurOrClick (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    togglebackground();
}

$(window).blur(blurOrClick);
$("#how-wall-link, #maximage, iframe").click(blurOrclick);
```